# Evaluating Card for a hand of Video Poker

Tags: c++

I sorted the cards by rank to make things easier. I sort of need to be guilded in the right direction on how I can set up these checks.

For example, to check for a straight, I know I just need to iterate through the sorted cards and see if each rank is one more than the previous card. Below is what I have for a straight.

For two pair, I'm not sure how to check for two successive cards that have the same rank, twice.

A full house is basically the same as a two pair, but the second (or first) pair is actually a triplet.

Four of a kind can be done the same way as three of a kind I'm pretty sure.

Straight flush is just a combination of straight and flush. A royal flush is a straight flush that begins with a 10 when sorted.

Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated and please supply examples (I also have a SortBySuit function if that helps).

```
NewGame.SortByValue();
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    tempHand[ i ] = NewGame.SetArray( i );

if( tempHand[ 0 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 1 ].GetValue() + 1 && tempHand[ 0 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 2 ].GetValue() + 2 && 
    tempHand[ 0 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 3 ].GetValue() + 3 && tempHand[ 0 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 4 ].GetValue() + 4 )
    winType = 4;
    //straight

//for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
//  for( tempHand[ i ].GetValue() == tempHand[ i + 1 ].GetValue() ||

for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    if( tempHand[ i ].GetValue() >= 11 || tempHand[ i ].GetValue() == 1 )
    {
        if( tempHand[ 0 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 1 ].GetValue() || tempHand[ 1 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 2 ].GetValue() || 
            tempHand[ 2 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 3 ].GetValue() || tempHand[ 3 ].GetValue() == tempHand[ 4 ].GetValue() )
            winType = 1;
    }
}//jack or better
```

Comment: currently the program is giving all pairs "Jacks or Higher" status.

Comment: This is not really a C++ specific thing, more of a language-agnostic thing

Comment: Could you please formulate your actual question more precisely?

Comment: English isnt first language. Not sure how else I can put it. I just need some insight on how they would compare the cards.

Comment: @JoshLake - are you still waiting for more answers? If my answer is not giving you what you are looking for then please give me some feedback and I will attempt to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with the highest ranked hand and work backwards... just as you would do with poker.

Do I have a flush? Is it royal?

Do I have a straight?
Do I have a full house?

Why start at the top? Because then you can safely break from the hand computation knowing that you have the optimal hand.
For the two pair problem/full house problem. You need to generalise your hand computation algorithm to take a number equal to or less than 7 (so you can also play hold'em), and then call it recursively until you have not cards left.

for example: Your hand is 3 J and 2 Q. 

Iteration 1 (passing in 5 cards)- detect 3 J.

Iteration 2 (passing in 2 cards)- detect 2 Q.

Final Pass - compute total worth of hand (made up of 2 solutions).

Same thing for 2 pair.

Iteration 1 (passing in 5 cards)- detect 2 J.

Iteration 2 (passing in 2 cards)- detect 2 Q.

Iteration 3 (passing in 1 cards)- detect 1 K.

Final Pass - compute total worth of hand (made up of 3 solutions). Detect 2 pair, queen high and a king. King is important as you could meet a matching hand, single card aside.

In short you need a recursive function that is called from a master function. Each iteration of the function should detect the **optimal** hand from the cards it has been passed.

Answer (score 0):

You're (1) checking for jacks last, and (2) not exiting early when you find a match.

Say you have a full house (Q-Q-Q-9-9).  If you check for a full house first, it'll match.  But then you might check for 3 of a kind (which would also match), and two pairs (which would match as well) and a pair (which would *still* match, because there are at least two Q's).  In the end, you'll end up saying that Q-Q-Q-9-9 is a pair of queens.

You need to either start with low-ranked hands and work up, or start from the highest-ranked and exit as soon as you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if you have a pair or a triplet, you could compute a type of histogram of cards.
For instance, iterate through all your available cards and increase the count of each number you find, such that if you had a hand

> 2 4 4 5 A

your bins would record

> Card - Count
>   A - 1
>   2 - 1
>   3 - 0
>   4 - 2
>   5 - 1
>   etc

You could then iterate through this and count the numbers of two of a kind, three of a kind, and four of a kind you have. 2 x two of a kind = two pair, 1 x two of a kind + 1 x three of a kind = full house.